# Specific Column sorting using tableSorter Jquery Plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Help please ,I have used tablesorter jquery plugin for sorting in my gridView.But Problems are ,,all columns  become sortable . I need some specific columns for sorting. How can I do it by using tablesorter.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ]'s and [ask]. You should also provide a [mcve] MY advice with the little info you have provided it to ditch tablesorter jquery plugin and use https://datatables.net/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s say that you want to sort all the tables on the page based on the values of the first column in descending order.

To do so, you have to pass a `sortList` property whose value is a `2D` array where the

- first element represents the 0-based index of the column to sort and the
- second element is 1 for the descending order and 0 for the ascending order.

Therefore to achieve the goal discussed you have to write:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
   sortList: [[0, 1]]
});
```

So in above example 0 is your first column and 1 is for descending order

You can also provide multiple columns like

```
$('table').tablesorter({
   sortList: [[0, 1], [2, 0]]
});
```

So in above example your table sort,  based on the values of the first column in descending order and the third column in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("table").tablesorter({
     // sort on the third column, order asc
     sortList: [[2,0]]
 });
```

In above code 2 is column 3 and 0 for ascending order.